# Need helping creating a Flex-box container that wraps and is even

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, layout, flexbox

Trying to create a 2 column, 3 row flexbox container for a food menu. The product elements (which should be 2 per row) do not wrap when shrunk. I'm looking for a way to create a wrapping layout using flexbox. Also, what would be the best way to use Media Queries for the product title to be displayed when the layout is shrunk for mobile-size?

I'm attaching my jsfiddle code:

https://jsfiddle.net/5ksd34nf/#&togetherjs=Ix1LEBTca6

(keep in mind without the images, the design changes so I'm attaching photos)

The HTML is:

`

```
<section class="menu-page" id="Menu">
    <div class="TitleWrapper">
      <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-list">

      <div class="product">
        <div class="imgwrapper">
          <img src="images/burger.jpg" alt="Burger" class="food-image">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <div class="product-content">
            <h3 class="name">Burgers</h3>
            <h3 class="price">10 &euro;</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="ptags">
            <p class="allergens">Allergens:</p>
            <p class="info">Milk, Gluten</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

How can I space out the Price from the Name using flexbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can do something like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.flex-sub-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .flex-item {
    width: calc((100% - 20px) / 2);
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  
  .flex-item:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-sub-item">
      <div>Title</div>
      <div>Price</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-sub-item">
      <div>Title</div>
      <div>Price</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```